# Combining display of points and polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Using QGIS 3.20, I am plotting a number of events with corresponding uncertainty ellipses, having one layer with the points and one layer with the ellipses (although both are stored in the same table in postgis). I would like to have this plotted with the newest data on the top. But if I put the ellipses as the upper layer, the oldest ellipses will obscure the newest event points - or the other way around. I tried to fake it by ignoring the events and plot the ellipses with centroid fill. This works relatively well when displaying large areas, but when I am zooming in closer, the calculated centroides starts to jump around (the dataset is in lat lon, but the project is in ETRS89 Lambert Azimutal).

Is it somehow possible to either combine points and polygons in one data set (I guess not) or is it possible somehow to order the plotting so that I get oldest points and oldest ellipses at the bottom and newest points and newest ellipses on the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you add the points to the ellipses symbology using the geometry generator instead of the centered fill.

Choose `point/multipoint` for geometry type, then use `centroid($geometry)` as your expression. Now your centroids wont adjust to the map canvas, but stay where they belong.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the feature ordering part of your question, you can control that using the `control feature rendering order` option in the `style`

[image]

Comment: This work between feature in the same layer but two different layer will always display on top of each other in the same order as in the table of content...

Answer (score 2):

Erik's answer (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/407853/10123) worked great, but the calculated centroids were for some reason off with a few hundred meters from the real event location - no idea why, but probably some problems with the initial calculations. But, the answer pointed me in the right direction with the geometry generator. As I said, I had the points in the same postgis table as the ellipses. When plotting the ellipses, the points come in as wkt with SRID information, e.g. SRID=4326;POINT(12.894309 53.845336). Throwing away the SRID, I can use the WKT to get back the point, using the following formula in the geometry generator:

```
geom_from_wkt( string_to_array("point",';')[1] )
```

Where "point" is the field in the table holding the event point.

It also works great the other way around, i.e. plotting the points and using the geometry generator to plot the uncertainty ellipse - in some cases that makes more sense. I.e. if you want to calculate if something is inside the ellipse, you plot the ellipse and calculates the event location. If you want to make an interactive map where the user is supposed to click on the point to get more info, the point should be plotted directly and have the ellipsis calculated